# What is the best log analyzer tool for linux server?

Tags: linux, log-analysis

I am currently working on setting up server which generates reports and upload them to external SFTP. I need a log analyzer which is possible free and runs on Linux server. Which one is the best solution?

I read a lot about SumoLogic, but not sure if this is the tool to go with.. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check goaccess.

GoAccess is an open source real-time web log analyzer and interactive viewer that runs in a terminal in *nix systems. It provides fast and valuable HTTP statistics for system administrators that require a visual server report on the fly.

http://goaccess.io/

Its pretty straight forward and free too.

Comment: thanks, but do you know if it can tell me that file was generated and uploaded to SFTP? or is beyond that tool ?

Comment: This tool will help you with the generation of reports in various formats using simple commands. A small shell script can be written to use this command to generate the file and upload to SFTP.

Comment: I am using different software (Jaspersoft) to generate reports and upload to SFTP, and i need to make sure that it was generated and uploaded by looking in the log. Sorry, I wrote my previous question  bit too confusing